# Is it possible to install Datadog on AWS using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, datadog

I saw this article which detailed on how to install Datadog on AWS using Ansible:

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/install-datadog-with-ansible-dynamic-inventories/

But the closest I could get to installing Datadog on AWS using Terraform was this:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/

The Datadog provider doc page shows how to use Terraform to do Datadog monitoring. But it does not talk about how to do installation of Datadog on AWS using Terraform.

Is it possible to install/setup Datadog on AWS using Terraform?

Please help!

Comment: AWS is an enormous platform - please be more specific on where you're trying to install Datadog.